# JBPM 6 Performance concern

Tags: drools, jbpm

Am inserting numerous facts in JBPM for rules matching and once the rules are matched i do appropriate actions needed. The number of facts will be numerous, with the size of 20k facts in memory JBPM takes following time to do following things:

```
Start Process - 3-4 seconds
Insert Fact - 4+ seconds
FireAllRules - 3-4 seconds.
```

Can someone please help me understand what could cause these delays.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the process may include rule compilation, which depends on the number of rules or lines of code in the DRL file(s).

The 4+ seconds are due to the evaluation of all rule conditions forall inserted facts. Of course, this not only depends on the number of facts, but also on the complexity of left hand side code (conditions). Whether 4+ sec is adequate cannot be said without inspecting the rules.

You can easily track what firing of rules means in terms of right hand side code (consequences). You have coded this, and you can monitor it very easily using an event listener. If this is too slow, check what that code does, and how.

Comment: Just a reminder that in Drools 6, `fireAllRules()` also includes the evaluation of the beta network in the RETE (or should I say PHREAK?) algorithm.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Good to know, thanks. This means, however, that the separate timing of LHS evaluation and RHS execution isn't straightforward any more (provided RHS doesn't mess with the WM contents anyway). One would have to register the first event of a rule execution to separate the beta network evaluation from RHS executions, correct?

Comment: That is actually a good question and I don't have an answer for it. I'll investigate a bit more.